# pagination for Thousands of records

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an application `(PHP/Laravel)` that read a Thousands of files (>5000) and display its content in a datatable like,
the problem i face is the page loading is very slow (an average of 3 minutes).

Is there a way i can display just say 50 records to clients and let the processing be done behind the scene till user to watching those 50 records?
or is there a way i can just display about 50 records and on next click, i can do pagination then for next 50 records for the user and display it.
what is the best way.
Here is what i did so far:

```
public function getMails(){
            $type = INPUT::get("type");

     $result = [];

           $all_files = Storage::allFiles('boite/'.$type);

            foreach ($all_files as $file){
                $file_content = Storage::get($file);


                preg_match_all('/x\-sender\:(.+?)\n/s',$file_content, $matches_);
                $x_sender = trim( $matches_[1][0] );

                preg_match_all('/Subject\:(.+?)\n/s',$file_content, $matches__);
                $subject = trim( $matches__[0][0] );

                preg_match_all('/x\-receiver\:(.+?)\n/s',$file_content, $matches);

                array_push($result, (object)["file_name"=> $file    ,"x_sender"=>$x_sender, "content"=>$file_content, "subject"=>$subject]);

            return view('list',compact('result'));
        }
```

and this my view:

```
@foreach($result as $mail)
    <li data-fname="{{$mail->file_name}}">
        <div class="md-card-list-item-menu" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click',pos:'bottom-right'}">
            <a href="#" class="md-icon material-icons">&#xE5D4;</a>
            <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-small">
                <ul class="uk-nav">
                    <li class="delete_mail"><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i> Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="md-card-list-item-date"></span>
        <div class="md-card-list-item-select">
            <input type="checkbox" data-md-icheck />
        </div>

        <div class="md-card-list-item-sender">
            <span>{{ $mail->x_sender }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="md-card-list-item-subject">
            <div class="md-card-list-item-sender-small">
                <span>{{ $mail->x_sender }}</span>
            </div>
            <span>{{ $mail->subject }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="md-card-list-item-content-wrapper">
            <div class="md-card-list-item-content" >
                {!! nl2br($mail->content) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [pagination with Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination), or perhaps a [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=opera&q=Laravel+pagination)? Please add the code you have written to get solutions to specific problems you are facing. Asking for possible approaches is too broad and hence not a good fit for the StackOverflow format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're reading files, make up some unique identifier to limit the number of records sent. An example: if you assume the unique identifier to be, lets say, the first letter of the files. Then, on the first Ajax request, send in a payload with value="A". This tells the server that it needs to send X number of files starting with A. If you want more files send A2,A3,A4.....B1,B2,B3...Z. you basically want to make a way for telling the server to identify the exact type and number of files to send. This is same as what we use with Db's. We send a payload of, initially, variable called page=10. This tells the server to send the first ten records. Then on the next request was send page=11. This tells the server to send record 11-21.  Apply a similar concept.

Comment: yes it's a good technique, i will try if i do not find another better solution

Comment: The solution I gave is rudimentary. Try to find a unique payload along the lines of my solution. Also, upvote and accept an answer and close the question. Update when you try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add good way to do it would add a limiter to the query, start position and end position. Pagenate it using the amount of rows then when the user clicks page 2, it uses an ajax call to pull the 2nd set of 50 down.

Comment: i am not using a database i am just reading the files and loop around them.